# argument of length 0 in for loop R

Tags: r, compiler-errors

I have 2 vectors of numbers. The vector "v" shows when a process starts in seconds. Vector u shows how much time does the proces in the vector u works.

I want to creeate a vector saying how many process are working at each second.
so this toy example: I create a vector "total" thats starts in second 0 (nevermind the end of the vector) and I will save in each position how many processes work in that second. So for example, in the first position of the vector(time 0) my code says I will have 1 process.

```
v <- c(0,1,2,3,4,5)
u <- c(1.2, 0.1, 1.2, 1, 0.5, 0)
j = 1
total <- rep(0, times = 10)
begin <- integer()
end <- integer()
repeat{
  begin<- v[j] +1 
  end <- begin + u[j]%/%1
  for(i in begin:end){
    if(total[i] == 0){ total[i] <-1}
    else total[i] = total[i] +1
  }
  if(j ==length(v)) break
  j = j+1
}

total
 [1] 1 2 1 2 2 1 0 0 0 0
```

I got this error(not here, in the real case):

```
Error in begin:end : argument of length 0
```

(I tried using an if in case begin = end) but  "for" should work for only one position.

What can be happening??

Comment: I would print the begin and end when the length is 0, without knowing the actual code it will be difficult to state what it is. Maybe the problem is in the definition of end. Why do you do [`%/%`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/Arithmetic.html)? Sometimes it can create errors. (see de documentation linked)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `seq.int` instead of `:` in this case. For example:

```
for (a in seq.int(from=3, to=3)) {                                                
  print(a)
}
[1] 3
```

Comment: It workded! (more or less) Now the problem is "Error: 'from' must be of length 1". I check it and all the values that 'from' gets are of length 1 ---if (length(v[i]) != 1)--> all FALSE. I was using the code as a function. Now i tryed with for, instead of repeat and its working.. Thank your all.

Comment: I saw the mistake... i was using it as a function and i wasn't giving the good variables to the function... T.T

Comment: Umm... I know this is fishing, but you should accept the answer if it worked for you. Thanks.

Comment: Sorry! :D I forgot to accept your answer! Thank you again.